# strange ruby behavior with a constant

Tags: ruby, constants, behavior

Could someone explain me, why my original constant `LIST` from the beginning is getting manipulated at the end? I thought constant could be just once initialized. I want to store the manipulations in a new array (`new_list`) without affecting the original one (`LIST`).

```
$ned = "foo"
$med = ""

print LIST = [:nrd, :mrd_y] # -> [:nrd, :mrd_y]


list = LIST

new_list = list.delete_if { |element|
  case element
  when :nrd then $ned.empty?
  when :mrd_y then $ned.empty? || $med.empty?
  end
}

print new_list # -> [:nrd]

print LIST # -> [:nrd] instead of [:nrd, :mrd_y]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Array#delete_if` -> Deletes every element of self for which block evaluates to true.

```
$ned = "foo"
$med = ""

LIST = [:nrd, :mrd_y]
p LIST.object_id #=> 84053120
list = LIST
p LIST.object_id #=> 84053120
new_list = list.delete_if { |element|
  case element
  when :nrd then $ned.empty?
  when :mrd_y then $ned.empty? || $med.empty?
  end
}
```

`List` and `list` holding the same `Array` object, as `object_id` tells above. Thus for each `true` evaluation from block `delete_if` deletes item from the object referenced by `84053120`. Which is kept by the `LIST` and `list`. so you can use the below:

```
$ned = "foo"
$med = ""

LIST = [:nrd, :mrd_y] 
list = LIST
new_list = list.dup.delete_if { |element|
  case element
  when :nrd then $ned.empty?
  when :mrd_y then $ned.empty? || $med.empty?
  end
}

p new_list #=>[:nrd]
p LIST #=>[:nrd, :mrd_y]
```

> Or (better approach use [`Array#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject)),

```
$ned = "foo"
$med = ""

list = [:nrd, :mrd_y]  
new_list = list.reject { |element|
  case element
  when :nrd then $ned.empty?
  when :mrd_y then $ned.empty? || $med.empty?
  end
}
p new_list #=>[:nrd]
p list #=>[:nrd, :mrd_y]
```

Comment: You could also use [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-reject) if that makes the block's logic cleaner. I think the `select` or `reject` approaches would be what I'd expect to see in Ruby code.

Comment: @muistooshort you are right! I for a while forgot about `reject`. Thanks for the pointer. updated now.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. in both case i wouldn't need the intermediate step `list = LIST` anymore, right (just `LIST.reject`)?

Comment: @ericMTR `yes` you don't need to have.I would suggest you not to use `constant` rather use `list` only with `reject`. `list = [:nrd, :mrd_y]` use this and `list.reject{..`. That's it.